# No search results are bound to material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm implementing Angular 2+ Material Table to my web app and I think I got most of it down. However, I am having a little difficulty getting the binding working. Basically, what I want to do is have a bunch of dropdown values and depending which values I select, those values get sent to server via api call to fetch items that match the values I pass. The matching results should be shown in the material table. Unfortunately, with the way I have it set up, nothing gets shown in the material table I currently have. I checked to see if I get values from the api call and I do get the proper values from my api call, so not sure why the binding itself is failing.

Here's my search function and some setup for the mat table:

```
displayedColumns = ['Store', 'SKU#', 'Department', 'Class', 'Material', 'Style', 'Description', 'LastUpdate', 'Active', 'RetailPrice'];
PRODUCT_DATA: Array<Product>;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.PRODUCT_DATA);
product: IProduct;

search(selectedDepartment: string, selectedClass: string, selectedMaterial: string, selectedStyle: string, isActive: string,
    productSku: string) {
    this._itemPriceMangerService.getProductsBasedOnSearch(98, productSku, selectedDepartment, selectedClass,
      selectedMaterial, selectedStyle, isActive).subscribe(data => {

        this.product = data;
        this.PRODUCT_DATA = this.product._products;

        this.dataSource.filter = this.storeId + productSku + selectedDepartment + selectedClass +
        selectedMaterial + selectedStyle + isActive; }); }
```

Here's my search button and material table:

```
<div style="padding:10px;">
        <button class="search" (click)="search(selectedDepartment.value, selectedClass.value, selectedMaterial.value, selectedStyle.value, selectedActive.value, this.productSku.value)">
            {{ 'Search' | translate }}
        </button>
    </div> 

    <div>
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Store">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{Store}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._storeKey}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="SKU#">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >  {{ SKU# } </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._productSkuKey}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Department">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ Department }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._department}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Class">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ Class }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._productClass}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Material">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ Material }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._productMaterial}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Style">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ Style }}</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._productStyle}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >  {{ Description}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._description}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="LastUpdate">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ LastUpdate }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._lastUpdatedTimestamp}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Active">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{ Active }} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">
              <select>
                <option *ngFor="let active of activeTypes" [ngValue]="active">{{product._isActive}}</option>
              </select>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="RetailPrice">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{'RetailPrice'}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">{{product._price}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
    </div>
```

When I do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.PRODUCT_DATA))`, this is what I get:

```
[
   {
      "_storeKey":98,
      "_productSkuKey":12345,
      "_department":234,
      "_productClass":12,
      "_productMaterial":"Material 1",
      "_productStyle":23,
      "_description":"Product Description 1",
      "_lastUpdatedTimestamp":"2018-03-16T13:54:49",
      "_isActive":"Yes",
      "_price":149.95
   }
]
```

So the data is there, just can't bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update data of your data source whenever you want to update data. So in your case you have to modify search function in this way:

```
...
this.product = data;
this.PRODUCT_DATA = this.product._products;
this.dataSource.data = this.PRODUCT_DATA;
...
```

So whenever you are getting updated data from server you have to set in `this.dataSource.data`. I can also see you are using filter, filter should be used only when you are filtering table locally but I guess in this case you want to perform search server side.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't get anything bound to my grid. Even with the addition of this.dataSource.data.

Comment: You didn't get anything after search or initially?

Comment: can you use `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.PRODUCT_DATA);` rather than setting data only?

Comment: ok I found an issue. I commented/removed the filter and I can see the data bound to my table now. I want to do the search above. Do I still need the filter to do a search where if I select value from dropdown 1 + dropdown 2... I want to filter the results to only show matching result with both those values.

Comment: if your search is server side, there is no need of filter. You can send the parameters to server and get the desired results. BTW if answer helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!